# Powershell Set default printer when the installation is done

Tags: powershell, printing

I have exported my network printers to an .xml file so they can be installed on a new PC.
Also, I haveexportet the default printer to a file so you can set a default printer after the installation.

The installation works fine. The problem is that the installation of the printers has not been completed before the script try to set the default printer.

This is my script to install the printers:

```
#Install the printer
$PrinterList = Import-Clixml H:\Backup\printers_export.xml

foreach($Printer in $PrinterList) {
  Invoke-Expression 'rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /q /n $($Printer.Name)'
}

# Set default printer
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter((get-content h:\Backup\DefaultPrinter.txt))
```

One solution I have found is to put a `Start-Sleep -s 15` after the first calls, can anyone point me to a better solution?

Comment: A couple of suggestions to try:  Assuming that `rundll32.exe` exits once the printer is installed, you could launch it with `Start-Process` using the `-Wait` switch, which will halt your script until the process exits (and the printer is installed).  Alternatively, wrap your `Start-Sleep` in a loop with a delay of, say, 5s, and use `Get-Printer` to check each time if the printer is listed as installed - when it is, set it as default and exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Add do/while loop condition to wait for default printer configuration is done. Like so:

```
$DP = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter((Get-Content H:\Backup\DefaultPrinter.txt))
do {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    [wmi]$wmi = Get-WmiObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer" | 
        Where { $_.Name -eq 'PUT YOUR DEFAULT PRINTER NAME HERE' -and $_.Default -eq $true}
}while(-not$wmi)
```

Comment: I have tried to do a Do/while and it works.

This is my do/while:

    do {
    Start-Sleep -s 1
    $DP = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter((get-content h:\Backup\DefaultPrinter.txt)) | 

    Where { $_.Name -eq $Printer.Name -and $_.Default -eq $true}
    }while(-not$DP)

The problem is that the script keeps running? What can you do to stop the script when the default printer is set?

Comment: You would want to request printer on every loop. Once it's there the variable should get data returned and no longer being null so it will let the loop quit. I have edited my answer that way it should better fit your needs.

Comment: I've tried but the loop keeps running

$DP = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter((Get-Content H:\Backup\DefaultPrinter.txt))

do {
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
   [wmi]$wmi = Get-WmiObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer" | 
   Where { $_.Name -eq '$DP' -and $_.Default -eq $true}
   }while(-not$wmi)

Comment: Perhaps I need a break statement?

Comment: @Joe, you could use break statement too. But current options is about the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is the script right now:

## Restore printer

$PrinterList = Import-Clixml H:\Backup\printers_export.xml

FOREACH ($Printer in $PrinterList) {

Invoke-Expression 'rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /q /n $($Printer.Name)'

}

RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters

## Set Default printer

$DP = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter((Get-Content H:\Backup\DefaultPrinter.txt))

do {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    [wmi]$wmi = Get-WmiObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer" | 
        Where { $*.Name -eq '$DP' -and $*.Default -eq $true}
}while(-not$wmi)

It does not work. 
Can not find the default printer and the script keeps running.

Comment: I've found another solution. Using Wait-Process -Name rundll32 just like boxdog wrote.
The script waits until the process is stopped and then a default printer is set

I still can't understand why that loop does not work. do you have any ideas?